# How to change <div> size based on devices

Tags: html, css, expressionengine

I am having a website already developed using Expression Engine. Currently if i open site on mobile phone or other device few sections cut off from the screen.

After debugging i found that i need  to change height of  DIV `<div id="tabmiddle" style="height:1500px;">` in respect of device. I am very new to expression engine.

I am looking out something like

```
    if (Mobile Device)
{
 <div id="tabmiddle" style="height:2000px;">

}else if(Tab Device)
{
<div id="tabmiddle" style="height:1800px;">

}else
{
<div id="tabmiddle" style="height:1500px;">
}
```

Comment: why not use `vh` to specify height as a percentage of viewport height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries).

> Media Queries is a module of CSS that defines expressions allowing to tailor presentations to a specific range of output devices without changing the content itself.

They allow you to apply specific styles based on the screen dimensions.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #tabmiddle {
    height: 1500px;
  }
}
```

This will change the height of your element with `tabmiddle` as the ID to `1500` pixels high whenever the screen is smaller than `600` pixels; typically a mobile/tablet device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following two media rules to do this:

For Mobile devices (width<768px):

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
  #tabmiddle{
    height: 2000px;
  }
}
```

For Tab devices (width<992px):

```
@media (max-width: 992px){
  #tabmiddle{
    height: 1800px;
  }
}
```

If device width is 992px or more than that, it will follow your default CSS height written in `style` tag of **tabmiddle** element.