# Change the width of a div depending on the device

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, responsive

I would like to use css to add an effect so that a div has a width of 500px but only if the user is on a computer. If the user is on a mobile phone, tablet, iPad etc, it would have the predefined width. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You should check what media query is !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change <div> size based on devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521778/how-to-change-div-size-based-on-devices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for media query, read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). If you are curious knowing different view widths, you can refer to this:-

1. 320px — 480px: Mobile devices
2. 481px — 768px: iPads, Tablets
3. 769px — 1024px: Small screens, laptops
4. 1025px — 1200px: Desktops, large screens
5. 1201px and more —  Extra large screens, TV

OR

You can use responsive units to set widths, like `100%` or `100vw`, know more about responsive units [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-best-css-unit-for-a-responsive-design-ku6q37to).

Answer (score 0):

Check this question if you want to detect device but anyway you would need media query. [What is the best way to detect a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)